# Fetch method POST - response data is Promise pending

Tags: reactjs, post, response

I have a component which does `fetch method='POST'` in one of its functions:

```
handleSubmit(context) {
    let json = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password,
    }
    json = JSON.stringify(json)
    fetch(`/api/auth/token/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: json,
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => this.loginSuccess(context, response))
}
```

And this is the `loginSuccess` function:

```
loginSuccess(context, response) {
    console.log('Login Success!')
    context.toggleLoginModal()
    context.toggleLoggedIn()
    context.setUsername(response.profile_username)
    context.setUserId(response.profile_id)
}
```

The problem with this code is, if the response doesn't lie between 200 and 300, like a **Bad Request**, all the code in `loginSuccess` will still get executed which shouldn't happen.

So, I have changed

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => this.loginSuccess(context, response))
```

to:

```
.then(response => {
    response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300 ?
            this.loginSuccess(context, response.json())
            :
            console.log(response)
})
```

Now, in `loginSuccess` method, the argument `response` is `Promise {<pending>}` and `response.profile_username` is `undefined`.

How do the solve this?

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise has not been fulfilled. Try something like :

```
.then(response => {
    response.ok ?
            response.json().then(json => { this.loginSuccess(context, json) })
            :
            console.log(response)
})
```